# We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: android, testing, store, playback, internals

App submitted for internal testing and closed track but the link for testing is not working even after 24h.

Comment: the title is very generic, could you provide more information please?

Comment: I submitted an app for internal testing and closed track but I can't access the app via the link

Comment: Could you share how long it took it to get accepted?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I'm having the same issues with multiple testers...